# I don't know how to solve this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Could you please help me compute the following integral: $$\int \frac{(x^2+x-4)}{x(x^2+4)}dx$$

What I've done so far is:

> $$\int \frac{(x^2+x-4)}{x(x^2+4)}dx = \int \frac{A}{x}dx+\int \frac{B}{x^2+4}dx$$

So

> $$x^2+x-4 = A(x^2-4)+Bx$$

And I did this so I could figure out the value of A and B but I am having a rough time trying to calculate A because of the $x^2$.

I've also seen that the solution solves this exercise by separating the fraction's numerator like this:

> $$\int \frac{(x^2+x-4)}{x(x^2+4)}dx = \int \frac{x^2}{x(x^2+4)}dx+\int \frac{x}{x(x^2+4)}dx + \int \frac{-4}{x(x^2+4)}dx $$

When do I know that I have to use this? Is what I though correct? If yes, how do I continue it?

Thank you very much. Please, let me know if something is not very clear in my question.

Agapita.

Comment: Have you heard about [trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)?

Comment: I am assuming you are familiar with partial fractions. When you have one of the denominator terms being an irreducible quadratic, note that you need $Bx + C$ in the numerator.

Comment: there is a misprint in your equation for A and B ,a minus sign should be + .in addition to the missing C

Comment: For you to check, your integral equals $$\log\frac{x^2+4}{|x|}+\frac12\arctan\frac x2+C$$

Answer (score 4):

Your partial fraction decomposition should be
$$\frac{x^2+x-4}{x(x^2+4)} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}. \tag{1}$$
Multiplying both sides by $x(x^2+4)$ results in
$$x^2+x-4 = (A+B)x^2+Cx+4A. \tag{2}$$
Consequently, $4A=-4 \implies A=-1$, $C=1$ and $A+B = 1 \implies B =2$.

After partial-fraction decomposition, the integral can be computed using standard transformations.

Comment: but how do you know that Bx+C should be in the numerator? Is it because you factorize x^2+x−4?

Comment: For Good answer +1.MathLover :)

Comment: @Agapita I suggest you to have a look at partial fraction decomposition. The degree of the numerator depends on that of the denominator. For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Examples.

Comment: @MathLover Your name confused me at first :)

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is to find $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that$$\frac1{x(x^2+4)}=\frac Ax+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

To make the finding of partial fractions slightly easier you may care to write
$$\frac{x^2 + x - 4}{x(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{(x^2 + 4) + x - 8}{x(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2 + 4} - \frac{8}{x(x^2 + 4)},$$
and then it is prehaps easier to guess/see that
$$\frac{8}{x(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{-2x}{x^2 + 4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

It must be
$$\dfrac{x^2+x-4}{x(x^2+4)}=\dfrac Ax+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}$$
then
\begin{align*}
x^2+x-4&=A(x^2+4)+(Bx+C)x\\
&=(A+B)x^2+Cx+4A
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The partial fractions decomposition is not what you think: it should be
$$\frac{x^2+x-4}{x(x^2+4)}=\frac Ax+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4},$$
because the  condition on the numerators is *not* they're constants, but  they're polynomials with degree less than the degree of the irreducible factor in the denominator. Here the second irreducible factor has degree $2$, so the numerator has degree $<1$.

To find the coefficients, multiply both sides of this equality by $x(x^2+4)$:
$$x^2+x-4=A(x^2+4)+(Bx+C)x.$$
Then set successively

- $x=0$, which yields $\;-4=4A+0$, whence $A=-1$,
- $x=2i$, which results in $\;2i-8= 0-4B+2iC$, whence $B=2$, $C=1.$
  Finally the integral becomes
  \begin{align}
  \int\frac{x^2+x-4}{x(x^2+4)}\,\mathrm dx&=-\int\frac{\mathrm dx}x+\int\frac{2x}{x^2+4}\,\mathrm dx + \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2+4}\\&=-\ln|x|+\ln(x^2+4)+\frac12\,\arctan \frac x2.
  \end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry but..could you explain me how you get Bx+C slower? Like if you were explaining it to a dummie hehe. Thanks :)

Comment: @Agapita: The *partial fractions decomposition theorem* asserts that for each irreducible factor $p(x)$ in the denominator, the corresponding numerator in the decomposition is a polynomial $a(x)$ such that $\deg a(x)<\deg p(x)$. If $p(x)$ is linear, this means $a(x)$ is a constant polynomial (degree $0$) and if $p(x)$ is quadratic, $a(x)$ is linear or constant. Is it clearer?